# Unity missing PostProcessing namespace in VS2019 Mac

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post-processing

I'm trying to dynamically change PostProcessing component values but the namespace for UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing won't be found!

[image: PostProcessing namespace missing]

I have:
..tried restarting everything
..installed & reinstalled the PostProcessing package (v3.1.1) via Package Manager
..tried using UnityEngine.Rendering & UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal
..successfully switch to URP

I can't find anything else to try. Anyone ever figured this one out?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using ASMDEFs?

Comment: This is the Kart Microgame and it IS using ASMDEFs! I'm checking to see if I can bridge the gap now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working! With help from 'Deleted'? Is that the handle or is that person gone?

In the Kart Microgame I just needed to add the Unity.Postprocessing.Runtime ASMDEF to the KartGame ASMDEF. Now my Kart scripts can see the Post Processing classes!

Thanks for the help!